# why does adding the same distribution to probabilities not change the percent?

Tags: probability

I'm curious on a more theoretical reasoning behind why adding 2 marginal distributions that are the same don't change the percentage. For example if I have 33 dogs and 66 cats and add 1 dog and 2 cats. It's still 33.3333333% dogs and 66.6666666666% cats. Why is this?

Comment: If $\frac ab=\lambda$ and $\frac cd=\lambda$ then $\frac {a+c}{b+d}=\lambda$, at least when $b+d\neq 0$.  Just write it out, using $a=\lambda b, c=\lambda d$.

Comment: @lulu sorry I'm not sure how the first 2 equalities leads to the third.

Comment: As I say, write it out.  Since $a=\lambda b, c=\lambda d$, $a+c=\lambda(b+d)$.

Comment: sorry I read it prior to you editing it. K I see it now